# How to Reverse String in Dart: Efficient String Reversal Techniques in Dart

Tags: string, flutter, dart, reverse, problem-spring

**By splitting the input string str into an array of individual characters, then reversing the order of the characters in the array, and finally joining them back together into a single string.**

```
// Function: firstReverse
// Input: str (a string)
// Output: a reversed version of the input string
// Description: This function takes a string as input and returns a reversed version of that string.
String firstReverse(String str) {
  // Split the input string into an array of characters,
  // reverse the array, and then join the characters back into a string.
  return str.split('').reversed.join('');
}
```

**By iterating over the characters of the input string in reverse order and appending each character to a new string revString. Finally, it returns the reversed string.**

```
String firstReverse(String str) {
  // Initialize an empty string to store the reversed string
  String revString = '';
  
  // Iterate over the characters of the input string in reverse order
  // starting from the last character (index: str.length - 1) to the first character (index: 0)
  for (int index = str.length - 1; index >= 0; index--) {
    // Append each character to the 'revString'
    revString += str[index];
  }
  
  // Return the reversed string
  return revString;
}
```

**Reverse String with the help of StringBuffer**
The first method utilizes Dart's StringBuffer class to efficiently construct the reversed string by appending characters in reverse order. This method is straightforward and efficient for reversing strings.

```
String firstReverse(String str) {
  StringBuffer reverseString = StringBuffer();

  for (int index = str.length-1; index >= 0; index--) {
    reverseString.write(str[index]);
  }

  return reverseString.toString();
}
```

**Reverse String with the help of CodeUnit:**
The second method converts each character of the input string into its Unicode code point using codeUnitAt, stores them in a list, reverses the list in-place, and then converts the Unicode code points back into characters using String.fromCharCode

```
String firstReverse(String str) {
  var stringToNumList = [];
  String reverseStr = '';

  for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    stringToNumList.add(str[i].codeUnitAt(0));
  }

  int start = 0, last = stringToNumList.length - 1;

  while (start < last) {
    var temp = stringToNumList[start];
    stringToNumList[start] = stringToNumList[last];
    stringToNumList[last] = temp;
    start++;
    last--;
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < stringToNumList.length; i++) {
    reverseStr += String.fromCharCode(stringToNumList[i]);
  }

  return reverseStr;
}
```

Comment: complexity -> 1 loop < 3 loops

Comment: Have you tried Dart – Runes

Comment: If you're dealing with Unicode strings, you can't just reverse code units.  You can't even reverse `Runes` (Unicode code points).  Reversing grapheme clusters is probably okay; you can use [`package:characters`](https://pub.dev/packages/characters) and do `str.characters.toList().reversed.join()`.

Answer (score 1):

**Method 1**

In Dart, one of the easiest ways to reverse a string is by using the split() method to split the string into individual characters, then using the reversed property to reverse the list, and finally joining the characters back into a string. Here's how you can do it:

```
  String originalString = "hello";
  String reversedString = originalString.split('').reversed.join('');
```

**Method 2**

you can use the codeUnits property of a string to get the UTF-16 code units of the characters in the string, then convert them back into a string. Here's how you can do it:

```
  String originalString = "hello";
  String reversedString = String.fromCharCodes(originalString.runes.toList().reversed);
```

**Method 3**

you can also reverse a string using a loop. Here's an example:

```
 String originalString = "hello";
  String reversedString = '';
  
  for (int i = originalString.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    reversedString += originalString[i];
  }
```

**Method 4**

you can use a StringBuffer to efficiently reverse a string in Dart. StringBuffer is a mutable sequence of characters that can be modified efficiently.

```
  String originalString = "hello";
  StringBuffer reversedBuffer = StringBuffer();

  for (int i = originalString.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    reversedBuffer.write(originalString[i]);
  }

  String reversedString = reversedBuffer.toString();
```

Comment: [As explained by the `String.split` documentation](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/String/split.html), `split('')` will split a string into individual UTF-16 code units, not on code-point boundaries.  Reversing the code units of a Unicode string is likely to generate an invalid string, and even reversing code points might not be appropriate either.  The other methods described in your answer would have the same problem.